# Free test environment (URL) to test my JMeter load tests?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Is there test environment (URL) which is available on the internet to practice my load tests?

I need to test my JMeter test simulating x2000 virtual users, is there a portal online which would enable me to test my newly created load test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Running load tests against public URLs is considered a Denial-of-Service attack. Don't do it.

You should instead run tests against localhost or some other server you own, as long as this is just for "practicing" your tests.

In case you need to mock a specific response, it may be easiest to use a http mock server like [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/), though simple request mocking can also easily be achieved with nodejs or similar.

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Comment: if i was to run tomcat locally on localhost:8080 and run a JMeter load test against the localhost url would that work?

Comment: yes. Tomcat, nodejs, django, jetty, netty, apache, ... so many choices.

Comment: thanks again for your help

Answer (score -1):

There are some sites which are designed for practicing load testing, i.e.

- http://blazedemo.com

According to the description

> The is a sample site you can test with [BlazeMeter!](https://www.blazemeter.com/)

There is also http://newtours.demoaut.com/ which is designed for practicing [QTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional) and/or [LoadRunner](https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/products/loadrunner-load-testing/overview) however I didn't find any explicit permission to test it with other tools.

---

In general it is better to use web application you own for exercises as this way you will be able to see the impact of your load using i.e. [PerfMon plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) so you will be able to analyse your results having way more information from the application under test infrastructure.

Comment: Those sites are provided to run the tutorials with the given load allowed in the tutorials, they are not free to be used with any load. All tutorial users share these resources, if some people bring down those sites with high load, other people trying the tutorials will get failures.

Comment: No reason to get personal, I did not even downvote your answer. The OP is asking about "practicing", so running test and stub on the same machine is no big deal, also sites like BlazeMeter cannot scale infinitely.

Comment: @Dmitri Thanks for the information, found it very useful